# Best way to handle UX confusion caused by an invalid PUT/POST in REST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

***My stack is Rails but the problem is actually framework independent***

**REST methodology says that**

In order to see an editing form for existing user:

```
GET: users/:id/edit
```

In order to update the existing user:

```
PUT: users/:id
```

**What this means for validation errors**

This is all sensible except when the form fails to validate. When the form doesn't validate the URL you end up on is not the `users/:id/edit` URL but instead:

```
users/:id
```

This causes two problems. One is navigation and the other is what happens if the user refreshes the form:

**A fresh editing form:**

[image]

**Same form with errors - although URL and nav suggest we're somewhere different**

[image]

Visually the page is now confusing as the nav and URL suggest that the user is not on the editing form but instead on the `resource#show` page.

**What the user sees if they now refresh the form - a completely different page**

It also has other implications. If the user is frustrated and just wants to reset the form their instinct will be to refresh the page. If they do that though they'll find themself on the `resource#show` page and not the `resource#edit` page.

[image]

Naively we might redirect an invalid submission back to the `resource#edit` URL. If we do this though we won't (by default in Rails) be able to show them the errors in the form they just submitted as these are stored in memory.

**Possible solutions**

As far as I can see there are two ways of solving this:

1. When `PUT users/:id` fails to validate: serialize the `user` object and store it in the session. Redirect to `GET users/:id/edit` and then unserialize the object on the next page to display the errors - *feels messy*
2. Change routing such that the `PUT` goes to `users/:id/edit` rather than `users/:id` - *also feels messy*.

**The Question**

What is the most appropriate way to solve this problem? I feel like the serialization approach probably makes the most sense but since it's not a part of Rails core I feel like I'm missing something. I know I'm not the first person to tackle this and am interested in others' approaches

Comment: No satisfactory answer here either, but see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047136/the-correct-way-to-handle-invalid-form-submissions-in-rails/5054434#5054434

Answer (score 1):

Well first off this is typical behavior in a rails application out of the box.

If someone submits an invalid form, then refreshes the page, what is supposed to happen?  In the case you have seen and in typical rails apps, we just refresh and (in the case of updating a record) possibly pop them out of the user experience.  IMO, that's OK.  Refreshing sometimes breaks the web :)

This is commonly seen when a designer wants to change the styling of the "invalid" page or a developer is looking at a rendering bug on the error page, they fix the code or css then refresh the page possibly expecting to see the page fixed but instead they might get and error related to /plumbers not accepting get requests or they get put back on the plumbers#index page.

Short answer is usually this isn't a big deal on most rails apps and it is done this way so that we don't have to rely on storing their answers and errors in session temporarily just to redirect back to the edit page, it all gets done in one request and response cycle.

If you want to change the behavior you can do something like

```
 class PlumbersController
    def update 
       plumber = Plumber.find(params[:id]) 
       if plumber.update(params[:plumber])
          redirect_to(plumbers_path, :message => "successfully updated!")
       else 
         flash[:plumber_attributes] = params[:plumber]
         redirect_to plumber_edit
       end
    end
    def edit
       @plumber = Plumber.find(params[:id])  
       @plumber.assign_attributes(flash[:plumber]) if flash[:plumber.present?]
    end
  end
```

NOTE: this code hasn't been tested.   The general idea is to pop plumber attributes into flash and redirect to the plumbers edit URL.

That said, the behavior your are describing is typical and the only way for rails to get around it is to rely on session (flash) for application logic, which it chooses not to do out of the box.

Comment: This is the same conclusion I came to. Thanks for documenting it though. I've upvoted it.